# RTL not working as expected in Nougat and later

Tags: java, android, localization

I have following string resource in Arabic local resource

```
<string name="status_created_seen_closed_text">"%3$s التعليمات في %2$s قام %1$s"</string>
```

I'm using `BidiFormatter` to handle RTL and LTL mixed text:

```
text = String.format( context.getString(R.string.status_created_seen_closed_text),
                            bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(statusTimeline.getEmpName()),
                            bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(TextUtils.getTranslatedStatus(context, StandardUtil.StatusType.valueOf(statusTimeline.getStatus().toLowerCase()))),
                            bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(dateStr));
```

but Im getting result as below :

`‏‪17 Dec,2018 06:22 PM‬‏ التعليمات في بانشاء قام ‏‪Khaled`‬‏

it seems every inserted text is in correct direction if consider individually but over all it seems Arabic texts are being inserted in English direction. My expected results are below

‏‪`17 Dec,2018 06:22 PM قام بانشاءالتعليمات في ‬‏    ‏‪‬‏Khaled`

**Edited** :

It's working correctly on Android M and below versions

Comment: Are you showing this text in a `Constraint Layout`? Or did you use any attribute to make the view which is showing your text `RTL`? Do you have `android:supportsRTL= "true"`  in your manifest?

Comment: yes im showing it in TextView. Tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for formatting your string:

```
String.format("%s %s %s %s", 
       statusTimeline.getEmpName(), 
       context.getString(R.string.status_created_seen_closed_text),
       dateStr,
       TextUtils.getTranslatedStatus(context, StandardUtil.StatusType.valueOf(statusTimeline.getStatus().toLowerCase()))
 );
```

and change your string resource value to :

```
<string name="status_created_seen_closed_text"> قام بانشاءالتعليمات في</string>
```

I guess it will solve the problem.

Comment: how we can use format this way ?`"%s %s %s %s" `. can you provide me any docs for it or demo

Comment: بانشاء its also a placeholder

Comment: @ZaidMirza I am using it in RTL text and it is just fine.

Comment: @ZaidMirza use above syntax to format you string and modify it to match your requirement. All the parts that you want to add to your message are strings that's why I used `%s`.